# How to return a value when chaining after looping an array inside a promise and pass it to the next promise as argument?

Tags: javascript, foreach, es6-promise

I am trying to fetch data from an endpoint. Still, everything works fine except a tiny mistake I believe I make which I am not well aware of this specific structure.

I am using a forEach() inside a .then() and now i want to pass the returned value for the forEach to the next chained .then() promise AND not creating a new .then() inside another .then()

```
const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
/*r = response, v = value, e = error, n = names array, iv = item value */

axios.get(url)
.then( r => r )
.then( r => r.data )
.then( r => r.map( v => v ) )
.then( r => {const n = r; return n} )
.then( n => { n.forEach( v => v) } )
.then( /* HERE I WANT TO IMPLEMENT THE RETURNED VALUE FROM THE PREVIOUS FOREACH() FUNCTION*/ )
.catch( e => e.respose ? console.log(e.response.status) : console.log(e.message) )
```

**CODE UPDATED**

```
axios.get(url)
.then( response => response.data )

/* Creates a copy from the responded array */
.then( 
  response => {
   const new_array = response.map( value => value )
   return new_array;
  } 
)

/* 
  Gets the name property for each value inside the copied array and stores it into a new array called names_array 
 */
.then(
  new_array => {
    const names_array = [];
    new_array.forEach(
      item => names_array.push(item.name)
    )
    return names_array
  }
)
.then(
  names => {
    console.log(names.sort( (a, b) => b-a) )

  }
)

/* Error handling */
.catch( e => e.respose ? console.log(e.response.status) : console.log(e.message) )
```

Comment: But `forEach()` doesn't return anything (it returns `undefined`)? That's why you should not use it, btw.

Comment: Is this your actual code? Neither `.then( r => r )`, `.then( r => r.map( v => v ) )` nor `.then( r => {const n = r; return n} )` make any sense.

Comment: Bergi the problem here is not the naming my friend.

Comment: And yes this is the actual code I am writing.

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to use the forEach to do? Also you have far more `then()` than are needed

Comment: The endpoint(https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users) returns an array with objects and each object has properties like name surname etc. Well I try for example to get the names and manipulate them in a different .then().

Comment: Do it in your `map()` which currently is useless and redundant

Comment: so chaining like this won't make the trick! I tried to implement it like this for the sake of clean code writing! Also as a matter of performance won't make things better?

Comment: Most of the chain shown makes no sense and is nothing more than useless code bloat

Comment: @evangelos They make no sense not because their naming is meaningless, but rather because all those callbacks do nothing. The produce exactly the same result value that was fed into them. Drop them and your code will work the same.

Comment: @charlietfl and Bergi thank you for your responses, my friends! Also, I updated the code could you please let me know if this approach is right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you want is an array of names from the response objects you are overcomplicating the whole thing with needeless `then()` in the chain.

Creating `const new_array = response.map( value => value )` is a pointless step that is simply making  copy of the original array for no reason

All you need is a simple `map()` to return the names in the first `then()`

```js
const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';

const getNames = () => axios.get(url)
  .then(res => res.data.map(o => o.name).sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b)))

getNames().then(sortedNames => console.log(sortedNames))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Very detailed explanation thanks @charlietfl. Correct me if I am wrong but,  mapping an existing array is always better than manipulating the original right?

Comment: Well `map()` returns a new array so you are not affecting the original at all